# Can you turn an Arel table back into a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I need Arel to do a few things that aren't possible with ActiveRecord, but my method should return a scope, since callers may want to add a few scopes of their own.

Is this possible?

e.g. `User.arel_table.scoped.first`

Comment: it would be more simple to help you if you explained what exactly you're trying to achieve. An arel_table is a very different beast from a scope, it is just a syntax node meant to help building sql queries. Some queries just don't make sense / don't meet the requirements to build an actual relation

Comment: Basically, can I use Arel's superior syntax to narrow down a given scope. It appears impossible, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: just to be sure, do you know that you can use arel statements in `Relation#where` ? e.g. 
`Model.where( Model.arel_table[:column].not_eq( nil ).or(Model.arel_table[:other_column].gt( 0 )) )`

Comment: Nooo, I didn't know that, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: If you give that as an answer, possibly with a link to docs, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use arel statements in `Relation#where`

example :

```
Model.where( Model.arel_table[:column].not_eq( nil )
               .or(Model.arel_table[:other_column].gt( 0 )) )
```

there's a good [ASCIIcast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) about it (arel is at the end). Additionally, you may be interested by [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).